# onCreate not getting called after finish()?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity A and an activity B. When I go from activity A to activity B, I use the following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class)
startActivity(i)
```

Now, when I want to return from activity B to activity A using `finish()`, the necessary method calls in my `onCreate()` method don't get called. Instead, my activity looks exactly how it is as when I left it...How do I get `onCreate()` to get called after using the `finish()` method?

**I have tested, and even the `onResume()` method doesn't get called after the `finish()` method in activity B.**

What is the problem?

Comment: Not clear what you are saying

Comment: ``onCreate()`` mothod only call when first time activity A called. When you start new intent, activity A will put in stack, and you call ``finish()`` function in Activity B, it just finish current activity and load activity A in stack (not re-call onCreate method).

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that onResume is not called?

Comment: @RogueBaneling I added toasts in `onResume` which didn't get displayed.

Comment: Check Activity Lifecycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle and make sure your ``onResume`` mothod is correct

Comment: Okay, well `onCreate` is not expected to be called, but all documentation says that `onResume` should be. http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Maybe post more code, as it is far more likely that you are missing something or have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Pls show code in ``onResume`` method, maybe problem in it

Comment: @RuchirBaronia make sure `show()` is called `Toast.makeText(this, "onResume called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`. Anyway try research about the `startActivityForResult` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)) that help in your case

Comment: @NamNH Ok so how do I return to the previous activity while also calling `onCreate`

Comment: @DanhDC Ok so how do I return to the previous activity while also calling `onCreate`

Comment: @RogueBaneling Ok so how do I return to the previous activity while also calling `onCreate`

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Im not sure why your logic placed in onCreate? If `startActivityForResult` not what you want. Try finish `A` when start `B`, and then from `B` start `A` again.

Comment: @RogueBaneling don't try call ``onCreate`` mothod, put your code in ``onResume`` function.

Answer (score 1):

OnCreate method will only be called when the activity is first created or re-created. Try to write a log in onResume or maybe post your code so we can inspect. Android provides full documentation of an Activity life cycle on their official website. You can look here [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: Ok so how do I return to the previous activity while also calling `onCreate`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in onCreate? Normally i would move my part of my code that is crucial such as checking session to onResume because onResume will definitely get called even activity is first created / re-created.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10985041)

Comment: @JaiprakashSoni If not mistaken i haven't reach 50 points to unlock the comment function